# Load issues with Java App - how to replicate?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jmeter, load-testing

I have a java application using oracle DB, running on apache tomcat. During normal day, the java app runs fine. However, the traffic was double on a day, and the app starts to encounter increase in response time and timeouts.

After that, we tried run load test using jmeter with the same amount of load experienced but never encountered any responsive/timeout issues from the testing. BTW, we checked our network monitoring tools, no issues with the infra.

Can I check what should I be looking for if I want to replicate the same issue during testing? Replicating this would help to ensure that the changes we are going to do would works.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your load test scenario save or update data in the DB? If yes, is the number of completed transactions in the DB after the test, equal to the number of playback iterations executed by virtual users? Or your scenario just selects data from the DB without performing transactions?

Comment: Yes. The test scenario will create records in the DB, and the records created match with the scenario.

Comment: I was looking at the actual logs again and it seems that the Java app was waiting for DB connections to be created. How can I replicate this in load? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Does your application require login? If yes, do you replay the JMeter script with the same user credentials as recorded?

Comment: Nope. No login required. Thanks!

Comment: Does your application use cookie based authentication? If yes, then I may have a suggestion for you.

Comment: Nope. It's not cookie based. Please share you suggestion though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The underlying question is: how to make the load test realistic enough to replicate slowness in accessing database observed in production. The thought process in our comments exchange was to review and rule-in or rule-out factors that are often not properly emulated in load tests and give over-optimistic performance result. I reviewed 4 factors:

1. Does the load test script correctly correlate dynamic values? Yes it does, because the records created by the load test match with the scenario. If this were not be the case, then failed transactions in the load test would be responsible for too fast response. The recommendation would be to correlate your script manually.
2. Does the load test script correctly emulate multiple authenticated users? Application does not require login. If this were not the case, then running load test with a single user will fail to test system overheads on maintaining multiple user sessions. The recommendation would be to parameterize recorded credentials using dataset with multiple credentials.
3. Does the load test script correctly emulate anonymous users authenticated through cookies? Application does not use cookie authentication. If this were not the case, then the recommendation would be to clear browser cache before recording to make sure that the stale cookie is not recorded and then make sure that cookie correlation in the script is configured properly.
4. Does the load test script correctly emulate data in the recorded scenario? Assuming the test scenario recorded some user entry that is used as a criteria for a database query. If you replay multiple iterations emulating the same entry, the database may not be hit for such queries due to application or database caching. If this is the case, then the recommendation is to parameterize user entries using test datasets.

If the last factor is also not the case, then there are more factors to go through. For more about correlation and parameterization load tests check this blog http://www.stresstimulus.com/blog/post/eradicating-load-testing-errors-1